# Unable to connect via bridge

Tags: wifi, bridge

I have a problem for a long time with my pi3 . In fact I have not managed so far blush to run my connection in bridge. I followed all the instructions of the various tutorials online but eventually changed the form but not the result. I have configured interfaces in this way:

```
auto lo 

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface default inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
      bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
      address 192.168.1.160
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 192.168.1.0
      broadcast 192.168.1.255
      gateway 192.168.1.190
      bridge_stp off
      bridge_maxwait 5

wpa-iface wlan0
wpa-bridge br0
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

But in the end I do not have the WLAN in bind to bridge:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# sudo brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.b827ebxxxxxx   no      eth0
```

Please, help me...

Comment: If you "followed all the instructions of the various tutorials online" your Pi (running an undefined OS) will be a mess! What are you ACTUALLY trying to do? What you have would NEVER have worked.

Comment: You can't bridge wireless networks. You have to use iptables with masquerading - take a look at: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: What operating system do you use? Because you are using `/etc/network/interfaces` it cannot be Raspbian. What access point to you want to use? Do you want a stand alone AP or should there be an uplink to an internet router? What interfaces do you want to bridge? **wlan0** and **eth0**?

Comment: There is no Raspberry Pi Model 3 available. What exactly is your model? RPi A3, RPi A3+, RPi B3, RPi B3+, CM 3, CM 3+?

Comment: Okay, first of all, thank you for your interest. Now let's do some clarity.

Comment: My Raspberry is PI3 model B, with Raspbian v 9 (stretch).So far I have always managed to connect to WiFi without problems, but once I create the bridge connection is not working. My bridge is made up of eth0 and Wlan0. From a standalone AP (Huawei R218).

Comment: Apart from wpa_supplicant.conf that I set with parameters of wireless connection, at the conf level everything else was cleaned up.

Comment: I have just modified rc.local in this way :                                                                  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE | 
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT |  
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT | 
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart |  

iptables-restore< /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat |                                                                                                                             And enabled packet forwarding in sysctl.conf.

Comment: @Dougie I have just followed that procedure with masquerading, but wi-fi connection was disappeared. I recovered it setting wlan0 parameters on /etc/network/interfaces. I setted so br0 as a static, and now see two interfaces, wlan0 and br0 with ani ip buto only wlan0 go out to Internet. I noticed that in the start-up phase the dhcpcd service fails, so stopped it and enabled networking by systemctl, but no changes that has solved...